# Перенести задачу с js в css

Tags: javascript, css

Есть код на js :

```
element.style.setProperty('top',(window.document.getElementById('list_element').children[i].offsetTop + 15) + 'px');
```

Можно ли расчет расстояния каждого элемента от `top` перенести в css, все таки  присваивать стиль будет намного быстрее через css, а не через js.

В цикле for создаются `div` элементы которые при создание выстраиваются в столбик, между ними нужно установить расстояние не менее 15px от верхнего `div` элемента. Стили такие как: ширина, высота, цвет, и тд, задал для всех элементов в css т.к. они одинаковые. А вот высота для каждого элемента на 15px должна быть больше чем для предыдущего, но пока только через js вышло это реализировать

Comment: добавьте пример вашей разметки и опишите, что происходит в приведенном коде

Comment: добавьте это все в вопрос

Comment: ага, и пример разметки добавьте которая в итоге получается